# Azure application status page

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-web-app-service

I have an application running on the Azure cloud.
Currently this is deployed as an Azure web app.

Is there any way to monitor the website status and build a page like [this](https://status.github.com) or [this](https://status.stripe.com)?

As you can see in those examples both have:

- a service global status
- An historical status which is grouped in hour/day/months period

Does azure has an API that I can use to monitor my services?

Comment: What about using a monitoring service like new relic? https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apis

Answer (score 2):

[Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-get-started/) and the Azure portal will give you a rich monitoring and diagnostics experience for your web app. It is in preview at this time.

You can get very granular data points or high-level graphs and trends.  The historical data can go back as far as 13 months for aggregated data points.  You can read more about the data retention policy [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-data-retention-privacy/).

The Azure portal (the new one at portal.azure.com) gives you a rich UI to interact with the telemetry data from your app.  And if you want to customize a blade to view specific data for your app you can do that too.

Azure Web Apps also has built-in monitoring support that you can use. It won't give you the depth that Application Insights does but you should look at [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-monitor/) too to see if it will give you the data you need.  And of course, you can customize the monitoring blades in the Azure portal to suit your needs.

Comment: The questions is about building public status page, so this does not really answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Azure does offer a robust RESTFul API for managing and monitoring your services. Essentially anything you can do through the Azure Management Portal is accessible via an API, including analytics. The portal itself often uses this same API.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx

You can also use MSFT authored .NET assemblies to create your own monitoring applications in Visual Studio. I find the monitoring and analytics features more robust via this model. These are available on GitHub:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/management-libraries-for-net-release-announcement/